# Java that adds time

Tags: java

I got Codes below, it generates my current time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
        String dateforrow = dateFormat.format(cal1.getTime());
        System.out.println(dateforrow );
}
```

Now How can I add hours to the current time? Like for example my current time ***4:30:00 PM*** , and I want to add ***8*** hours to it, so maybe the output is ***0:30:00 AM.*** I have no Idea.

Comment: Calendar.add `cal1.add (Calendar.HOUR, 8);`

Comment: Java 8 way : 
LocalTime dateTime = LocalTime.now(); // will give you current system time 
 System.out.println(dateTime.plusHours(2)); //add 2 hours to the time

Comment: @Mehraj Malik That works but it returns a 24 hours format. (e.g 19:00:00)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
    cal1.add(Calendar.HOUR, 8);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
    String dateforrow = dateFormat.format(cal1.getTime());
    System.out.println(dateforrow );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
        Date date = cal1.getTime();
        //add two hour
        date.setHours(date.getHours()+2);
       cal1.setTime(date);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");

        String dateforrow = dateFormat.format(cal1.getTime());
        System.out.println(dateforrow );
```

add two hour